# Binding variables in C?

Tags: c, macros, callback

I am working an a project in C that is highly asynchronous. Unfortunately, it is quickly becoming apparent that there is a lot of boilerplate in the form of specifying structs that contain userdata for callbacks.

For example:

```
typedef struct SomeUserData {
  int foo;
  int bar;
} SomeUserData;

void someCallback(void * userData)
{
    SomeUserData * myData = userData;
    // ...
    free(myData);
}

void someFunc(void)
{
    SomeUserData * myData = calloc(1, sizeof(*myData));
    myData->foo = 5;
    myData->bar = 10;
    doSomeAsync(someCallback, myData);
}
```

It's not so bad when there are just one or two callbacks, but the part of the project I'm working on now has hundreds due to the number of asynchronous steps involved.

What I'd love to have is something akin to `bind` in C++. Is there a way to achieve a similar result with some C macro trickery or even something at runtime using variadic arguments?

Comment: I don't think so... You could get rid of the void* by having the callback take SomeuserData* and have doSomeAsync with the right signature.  That's what C++ does for you under the hood through templates.

Comment: If there is enough uniformity, this may be a good time to consider code generation. Use python or something to process a single input file in (XML, CSV or whatever) and generate all the appropriate header and source files for defining the callback data structures and functions prototypes. If the function themselves are simple enough you may even be able to generate them. There can be a significant saving in terms of duplicated code to be maintained.

Answer (score 1):

C macro trickery isn't always the easiest to debug, but:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Type1 {
    int foo ;
} Type1 ;
typedef struct Type2 {
    char* bar ;
} Type2 ;

#define CALLBACK( Type ) \
    void my##Type##Callback( Type* myData ) ; \
    void Type##Callback( void* userData ) \
    { \
        my##Type##Callback( (Type*) userData ) ; \
        free( userData ) ; \
    } \
    void my##Type##Callback( Type* myData )

CALLBACK( Type1 )
{
    printf( "Type1=%d\n", myData->foo ) ;
}

CALLBACK( Type2 )
{
    printf( "Type2=%s\n", myData->bar ) ;
}

void doAsync( void (*callback)( void* ), void* data )
{
    (*callback)( data ) ;
}

int main()
{
    Type1* t1 = calloc( 1, sizeof(*t1) ) ;
    Type2* t2 = calloc( 1, sizeof(*t2) ) ;
    t1->foo = 42 ;
    t2->bar = "TheAnswer" ;
    doAsync( myType1Callback, t1 ) ;
    doAsync( myType2Callback, t2 ) ;
}
```

might help.  It declares a "myXXXCallback" taking a pointer to the specified type, then creates a "XXXCallback" taking a void* that calls the type-specific version and then frees the data.  The "trick" is using the "##" operator to join the passed-in type into the function names.